# iOS: Unknown classes in reflection

Tags: ios, objective-c, reflection

At runtime, when listing the classes in my main bundle (using `objc_getClassList`). I see things like :

```
_TtGCs18ManagedProtoBufferVs29_HashedContainerStorageHeaderVs5UInt8_
_TtGCs13ManagedBufferVs29_HashedContainerStorageHeaderVs5UInt8_
_TtGCs28_NativeDictionaryStorageImplCSo8NSObjectPs9AnyObject__
_TtGCs18_HeapBufferStorageVs18_StringBufferIVarsVs6UInt16_
```

Any ideas what those are??

Also, they do not *always* appear...

I also see `NSKVONotifying_NSUserDefaults` sometimes.